# REST Endpoint always downloading the image twice in POSTMAN

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Spring boot REST Endpoint is always downloading the image twice when used in POSTMAN. The inline/attachment is also not working , its always downloading it even if used as inline . This is not a duplicate question in stackoverflow , as it is always downloading the image twice .

1. Code for inline :

```
File invoiceImage = invoiceService.getInvoiceImage(id);
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok().header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" +invoiceImage.getName()).
                contentType(MediaType.valueOf(Files.probeContentType(invoiceImage.toPath())))
                .body(Files.readAllBytes(invoiceImage.toPath()));
```

2.Code for attachment :

```
File invoiceImage = invoiceService.getInvoiceImage(id);
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok().header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +invoiceImage.getName()).
                contentType(MediaType.valueOf(Files.probeContentType(invoiceImage.toPath())))
                .body(Files.readAllBytes(invoiceImage.toPath()));
```

Comment: found that downloading twice is a bug in postman : https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/615

Comment: But the only issue which is not resolved is : its always downloading but not showing image , even though we use inline